# How to search database in Visual Studio? (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, database, select, passwords

I am working on a side project(student, not homework, just holiday curiosity), which would be my simple personal password manager/vault. It will be a windows app. I want it to support more than just one user. Now that i have my login screen and other functionalities, i struggle to find a simple and effective way to check if login and password of the user are correct. I store the information in a simple SQL table called Users(picture below). Now, i want to get the bool result, whether are these two strings (username,password) in database. i will include some code and screenshots below. Any help appreciated!

P.S.: I am pretty familiar with mySQL(Oracle), i just can´t fin a good way to do this without being ridiculous. :)

```
namespace KeyLocker.Database {
[Serializable]
public class UserDatabase {
    public void AddUser(string username,string password,string question,string answer) {
        using(var db = new KeyLockerContext()) {
            db.Add(new User { Username = username,Password = password,SecurityQuestion = question,SecurityAnswer = answer });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public bool CheckUser(string username,string password) {
        using(var db = new KeyLockerContext()) {
            /*here i need to find out if username is present in database
              and if it is, i need to find out if the password is correct*/
        }
    }
}
```

}

[Table Users ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjt4E.png)

[Table SQL detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKvQr.png)

Comment: Obligatory "you should never store plaintext passwords" comment.

Comment: i changed the code to simpler format so the question would be easier to comprehent. but thanks for the heads up anyway :)

Comment: What @itsme is getting at is storing and checking passwords is actually quite a difficult problem, and naïve solutions like storing and comparing text is both insecure and ineffective. “security questions” are also a problematic concept. It's great you want to learn this, but please learn it right so we can reduce the number of data breaches, not increase them.

Comment: firstly, i am not going to use this in any way.i use it on isolated pc out of the network with made up database. The point was not to use it IRL, just to try and get the concepts of windows apps. i worked on C# projects before (mostly .ASP web apps), but i am curious about the windows apps. i understand the urgency and the caution i have to take when working with passwords. I know you mean it in a good way! and it is great that you are taking such measures to prevent newbies from doing such mistakes :)

Comment: "There is no such thing as prototype code" (something you will learn very quickly in industry). Always do things as right as possible, you may not get a chance to clean it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, it seems like the easiest code to execute your idea would be:

```
public bool CheckUser(string username,string password) {
    using(var db = new KeyLockerContext()) {

        // Check if that combination already exists in DB.
        var result = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username == username && x.Password == password).SingleOrDefault();

        // See if result has a value, SingleOrDefault() returns null if no match
        return (result == null);
    }
}
```

EDIT/Disclaimer: Since there seems to be some confusion, this is an idea for how to quickly check if an object w/ certain values already exists in the DB - not a complete authentication library.  You should never store cleartext passwords.

Comment: Obligatory "this implies your passwords are in plaintext, don't do that" comment

Comment: that is what i was looking for. i somehow missed the "Where" Method. thank you for quick response!

Comment: [Please don't do this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12641/), not only is it insecure, if your users ever reuse a password on another site you're leaking that password too.

Comment: Note that you don't need `Where` at all. You can pass the predicate to `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: Thank you, i will look around and will keep that in mind for the future :)